# Was the final shot of Halt and Catch Fire S3/Ep8 done with a green screen?

Tags: film-techniques, film-location, halt-and-catch-fire

Specifically, that incredible [dolly zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom) where a broken Joe MacMillan stands at the base of the Golden Gate Bridge.

The reason I ask is the background with the bridge looks *too perfect*, but on the other hand, they had definitely done at least one live action scene around that spot in a previous episode, which suggests some degree of location shooting in SF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible that the *final* shot was green screen or a composite but the run-up is a moving shot showing him walking towards the bridge.

The evidence suggests to me that this was, in fact, shot **on location** even if the final shot was, indeed, a composite.

[image]

[image]